# push_back(new triangle)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fltk

In C++ by FLTK, to define a circle we use some code like this:

```
Circle c(Point(x,y), r);
```

And we can using vector_ref put and save them in a vector, like:

```
Vector_ref<Circle> vc;
vc.push_back(new Circle(Point(x,y),r));
```

OK, those were about Circle and no problem till now!
Triangle can be defined like this for using in codes:

```
Graph_lib::polygon poly;
poly.add(Point(x1,y1),r1);
poly.add(Point(x2,y2),r2);
poly.add(Point(x3,y3),r3);
```

and this is a vector to saving them:

```
Vector_ref<Graph_lib::Polygon> vp;
```

The problem is that how to save/put `triangles/polygons` into that vp vector using `new` keyword like the circle does?

The code I used as an answer to the exercise no 12 (of [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20principle%20and%20practice&pg=PA517#v=onepage&q&f=true))
  is this:

```
/* The binary-tree class, one of the topics that has been said in Programming Principles and Practice using C++ book by Biarne Stroustrup.
   This code is written by R Abbasi (s.rabbasi@yahoo.com) */
#include <Simple_window.h>
#include <iostream>

vector <Graph_lib::Polygon> vpo;
vector <Point> vp;
int pow(int);

class Binary_tree: public Shape {
public:
    Binary_tree(Point _p, int l):level(l), p(_p) {  
        preparing(); }

    void preparing();
    void put_nodes(Point);
    void wheel(Point);
    void make_nodes(Point);
    void draw_lines() const {
        for(int i = 0; i*2+2 < vp.size(); i++) {
            fl_line(vp[i].x,vp[i].y,  vp[i*2+1].x,vp[i*2+1].y);
            fl_line(vp[i].x,vp[i].y,  vp[i*2+2].x,vp[i*2+2].y);
        }
    }

private:
    Point p;
    int i, j, k, level;
    double scale;
};
//**********************************

void Binary_tree::preparing() {
    if(level < 1) error("Bad inputted level!");
    else if (level == 1) put_nodes(p);
    else {
        scale = 5 * pow(level); 
        i = 1; j = 1; k = 3; 
        put_nodes(p); 
        make_nodes(p);
    }
}

//***************************************

void Binary_tree::put_nodes(Point p) { 
    vp.push_back(p);
    Graph_lib::Polygon poly;
    poly.add(Point(p.x-2,p.y));
    poly.add(Point(p.x,p.y-3));
    poly.add(Point(p.x+3,p.y));

    vpo.push_back(&poly);
}

//******************************************

void Binary_tree::wheel(Point p) {
    put_nodes(Point(p.x - scale, p.y+30));
    put_nodes(Point(p.x + scale, p.y+30));
}

//*****************************************

void Binary_tree::make_nodes(Point p) {
    while(vp.size() < (pow(k)-1))
        wheel(vp[vp.size()-i++]);

    if(i < pow(level)) {
        k++;
        scale *= 1.0/2.0;
        make_nodes(vp[vp.size()-i]);
    }
}

//*********************

int pow(int l)  {
    int m = 2; 
    for(int k = 2; k < l; k++) m *= 2; 
    return m;
}

//***************************************

int main() try
{
    Simple_window win(Point(),1300,500, "Binary_tree");
    int level;
    cout<< "Please enter the level of the Binary-tree:";
    if(!(cin>>level)) error("Bad number of level!");

    Point p(10*pow(level),20);
    Binary_tree b_t(p,level);

    vpo[0].set_color(Color::red);
    vpo[0].set_style(Line_style(Line_style::solid,3));
        win.attach(vpo[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<vpo.size(); i++) {
        vpo[i].set_color(Color::blue);
        win.attach(vpo[i]);
    }
    win.attach(b_t);
    win.wait_for_button();
    return 0;
}

//*****************************

catch(exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << "\n\a";
    return 0;
}
```

And errors are:

*Error  9   error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(Graph_lib::Polygon &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Graph_lib::Polygon *' to 'Graph_lib::Polygon &&'  c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test_1\test_1\test_1.cpp  53

14 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=Graph_lib::Polygon, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Graph_lib::Polygon *)
            object type is: std::vector> c:\Users\CS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_1\test_1\test_1.cpp  53*

Comment: Do you really need to use `new`? If you do, you should say why. And explain how pushing a `Circle` pointer into a vector of `Circles` works.

Comment: I guess you should draw your class inheritance.

Comment: You will get a syntax error if you use new.  Just use vc.push_back(Circle(Point(x,y),r)) - Have a look at your poly example - you don't use new there.

Comment: C++ makes the distinction between pointers, references, local objects and temporary objects. You have to use the right form. When a function expects a dynamically-allocated object (i.e. a pointer), then use the `new` keyword. Otherwise, you must pass in a temporary object without the `new` keyword, and a copy of that object will be made by the function. This description is a simplification - you should have an introductory C++ book with you during the first 6 months of learning C++.

Comment: @cup: Using _vc.push_back(new Circle(Point(x,y),r));_ (in above code) doesn't make any error while the _vc.push_back(Circle(Point(x,y),r));_ makes _Debug Assertion failed_ error. So I need to use of new. Anyway, my problem is not circle, it's polygon. I need a way to push polygons into the vector or vector_ref.

Comment: @rwong: I'm reading [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming1.html) book and the exercise related to my problem is no 12 of [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20principle%20and%20practice&pg=PA517#v=onepage&q&f=true).

Answer (score 2):

### For `Vector_ref<polygon>` (using `new`)

From what I understand of `Vector_ref`, this is simply a `std::vector` with pointers and code to clean up the dynamically allocated memory at the end.  This means you must use `new` to allocate your polygon. So, if you must use `new`, you can create your polygon first (using `new`) and then push it:

```
// Create your new polygon
polygon* poly = new polygon;
poly->add(Point(...));
poly->add(...);
poly->add(...);

// Push that polygon into the vector
vp.push_back(poly);
```

### For `std::vector<polygon*>` (taking the address)

If the polygon doesn't go out of scope (i.e. you don't leave the function or pass a `}`) you can take the address of the polygon:

```
// Create polygon
polygon poly;
poly.add(...); // by 3

// Add the polygon to the vector
vp.push_back(&poly);
```

### For `std::vector<polygon>` (making a copy)

If the vector is not an array of pointers, which is the case for `std::vector<polygon>` (but not for `std::vector<polygon*>` or `Vector_ref<polygon>`), then you should not use `new` or `&`.  Instead if you just use `push_back` of the vector with the polygon, the polygon will be copied into the vector.

```
// Create your new polygon
polygon poly;
poly.add(...); // by 3

// Copy the polygon into the vector
vp.push_back(poly);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a simple and correct one. But since I haven't learned pointers until that part of the book (I offered its link above) I can't use of pointers and should by some other way solve the problem :(

Comment: Whenever you use the `new` keyword you are using a pointer.  In this case I have assigned the pointer to a variable (denoted by the `*`).  The only other difference is accessing members of pointers, instead of the `.` you can use `->`.

Comment: @user3724662 I have added an alternative, this still uses a pointer but hides it (mostly).  Your original circle example used a pointer too, since it used the `new` keyword.

Comment: I used the second method and added he whole code into the question body. There are errors. Please look at the question once again.

Comment: @user3724662 Ah, I see.  I assumed you were using `Vector_ref` for your polygons, not `std::vector`.  As far as I can tell `Vector_ref` is an array of pointers with some clean up code.  For your case you should be able to just use `push_back` with no fancy extras.  If that doesn't work, post your new compiler output.  Good luck.

Comment: Instead of `vector_ref` of polygons which would make many complexity I used a `vector_ref` of `Lines` which is a kind of `Shape` as well and is just like `Circle` (for putting into the `vector_ref`). Triangle is made of 3 lines so using `Lines` I could solve the problem. Thanks :)